# i need to combine two JOIN conditions in a single mysql stament

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables: `destinations` and `prices`.
destinations have 2 fields: ID and NAME
prices have 4 fields: ID_FROM(ID from destinations), ID_TO(ID from destinations), PERSONS, PRICE

I need to make a SQL statement were to change ID_FROM with correspondent NAME and the same for ID_to.

using JOIN in a SQL statement I can only do for one at a time but I need to combine somehow and get both NAMES in the same statement

this works separately:

```sql
SELECT     b.name
FROM       dm_prices a
INNER JOIN dm_destinations b
ON         a.from_id = b.id
```

```sql
SELECT     b.name
FROM       dm_prices a
INNER JOIN dm_destinations b
ON         a.to_id = b.id
```

but I need to combine both in a single query

Comment: Just use multiple `JOIN` statements in your `SELECT` query, each with a different alias.

Comment: you are right Sergio. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join twice the table `destinations` to `dm_prices`:

```
select
  df.name name_from,
  dt.name name_to
from dm_prices p
inner join dm_destinations df on df.id = p.id_from
inner join dm_destinations dt on dt.id = p.id_to
```

If there is a case of either of the columns `id_from` or `id_to` to be `null` then instead of `inner join`s use `left join`s.